# Conflict between files

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing an MVC3 application, it uses a database. I feel like I'm having conflicts with previous projects and databases. I have tried to use the name User in table and it tells me invalid object name dbo.Users and i didn't even write anywhere UserS with an S, when I use dumb names like a table name One and a class One, there is no problem.

I have deleted previous project files but no luck, been having this problem for days.
I haven't been able to  start my project because the names that make sense have somehow been "taken or are creating conflicts", is there a way, to clean visual studio files???

Help!! =S I'm desperate...

Answer (score 0):

How to clean the solution? To clean, right click the solution node in the solution explorer and select clean solution

Comment: I tried using clean and it didn't work, this makes no sense, there shouldn't be a conflict with names because it is a complete different database I click app_data add new item...etc! =(

Comment: Is there any way it is using the debug version of your database instead? It could be something as simple as a physical file path issue. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have just found it: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/entity-framework-invalid-object-name-dbo-albums/

It was because it was making the name of the table to a plural form, I have NO idea why!